# XML/XSL 1.0 Group in section by attribute

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I want to create a section by grouping my xml entries by attribute "Headline" with XSLT 1.0

My XML File:

```
<ProductFeatureRecord Type="Detail">
<Data>
<Feature FeatureID="27219" Description="Myheadline" FeatureType="Headline" ></Feature>
<Feature FeatureID="33751" Description="Myboolean" FeatureType="Boolean" />
<Feature FeatureID="35668" Description="Myvalue" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="25935" Description="Mygroup" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="21567" Description="Myvalue" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="20894" Description="Mygroup" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="17021" Description="Myboolean" FeatureType="Boolean" />
<Feature FeatureID="26225" Description="Myheadline2" FeatureType="Headline" />
<Feature FeatureID="20591" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="31680" Description="Mygroup2" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="30882" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
<Feature FeatureID="30883" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
</Data>
</ProductFeatureRecord>
```

Current XSL file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ProductFeatureRecord/Data/Feature">
<xsl:if test="@FeatureType='Headline'">
<section><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<dl><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<h2><xsl:value-of select="@Description"></xsl:value-of></h2><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</dl><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</section><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@FeatureType='Boolean'">
<dt><xsl:value-of select="@Description"></xsl:value-of></dt><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><dd>ja</dd><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@FeatureType='Value'">
<dt><xsl:value-of select="@Description"></xsl:value-of></dt><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><dd><xsl:value-of select="@FeatureValue"></xsl:value-of></dd><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@FeatureType='Group'">
<dt><xsl:value-of select="@Description"></xsl:value-of></dt><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><dd><xsl:value-of select="@FeatureValue"></xsl:value-of></dd><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But my section and dl tags are not correct closed now :/ any idea how to fix this to get this output?

```
<section>
<dl>
<h2>Myheadline</h2>
<dt>Myboolean</dt>
<dd>ja</dd>
<dt>Myvalue</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Mygroup</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Myvalue</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Mygroup</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Myboolean</dt>
<dd>ja</dd>
<section>
</dl>
</section>
<dl>
<h2>Myheadline2</h2>
<dt>Myvalue2</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Mygroup2</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Myvalue2</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
<dt>Myvalue2</dt>
<dd>1</dd>
</dl>
</section>
```

Comment: The output that you show is not well-formed!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. It looks like you want to group the entries so that every `Feature` where `"@FeatureType='Headline'` starts a new section, with all the following Features included. If so, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="group" match="Feature[not(@FeatureType='Headline')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Feature[@FeatureType='Headline'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="Feature[@FeatureType='Headline']">
        <section>
            <dl>
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
                </h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', generate-id())"/>                 
            </dl>
        </section>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Feature">
    <dt>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <xsl:value-of select="@FeatureValue"/>
    </dd>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Feature[@FeatureType='Boolean']">
    <dt>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
    </dt>
    <dd>ja</dd>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<ProductFeatureRecord Type="Detail">
    <Data>
        <Feature FeatureID="27219" Description="Myheadline" FeatureType="Headline" ></Feature>
        <Feature FeatureID="33751" Description="MybooleanA" FeatureType="Boolean" />
        <Feature FeatureID="35668" Description="Myvalue" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="1" />
        <Feature FeatureID="25935" Description="Mygroup" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="2" />
        <Feature FeatureID="21567" Description="Myvalue" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="3" />
        <Feature FeatureID="20894" Description="Mygroup" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="4" />
        <Feature FeatureID="17021" Description="MybooleanB" FeatureType="Boolean" />
        <Feature FeatureID="26225" Description="Myheadline2" FeatureType="Headline" />
        <Feature FeatureID="20591" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="5" />
        <Feature FeatureID="31680" Description="Mygroup2" FeatureType="Group" FeatureValue="6" />
        <Feature FeatureID="30882" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="7" />
        <Feature FeatureID="30883" Description="Myvalue2" FeatureType="Value" FeatureValue="8" />
    </Data>
</ProductFeatureRecord>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<section>
   <dl>
      <h2>Myheadline</h2>
      <dt>MybooleanA</dt>
      <dd>ja</dd>
      <dt>Myvalue</dt>
      <dd>1</dd>
      <dt>Mygroup</dt>
      <dd>2</dd>
      <dt>Myvalue</dt>
      <dd>3</dd>
      <dt>Mygroup</dt>
      <dd>4</dd>
      <dt>MybooleanB</dt>
      <dd>ja</dd>
   </dl>
</section>
<section>
   <dl>
      <h2>Myheadline2</h2>
      <dt>Myvalue2</dt>
      <dd>5</dd>
      <dt>Mygroup2</dt>
      <dd>6</dd>
      <dt>Myvalue2</dt>
      <dd>7</dd>
      <dt>Myvalue2</dt>
      <dd>8</dd>
   </dl>
</section>
```

**Note**: this is a variation on [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). You need to be familiar with the method before you can understand this.